# How to configure Spring Boot with Liquibase and H2 to use a non-admin account by default

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster, h2

I'm using a JHipster-generated application that uses liquibase to populate a persisted H2 database. As a security requirement, we need to set up and use a non-admin user on the database so that in normal operation, the Spring application uses a limited database account which, for example, would not be able to alter the schema.

Currently there seems to be a default H2 user that is automatically created via SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME and SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD properties. Presumably this auto-generated user has all the admin power that lets the application create and populate tables via liquibase. Ideally this would continue to work as-is, but all other Spring db operations would work over a different user with more limited permissions.

Playing around with the H2 database, I can see H2 does include commands that make it possible to create new users with very granular levels of access, but it's not clear how to set up Spring to make use of this alternate user.

EDIT: I looked at the solution posted here: ([Liquibase & Spring how to use separate user for schema changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774525/liquibase-spring-how-to-use-separate-user-for-schema-changes)), but I'm running into a few issues.  The solution proposes setting up an application yaml like the following:

`application.yml`:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mariadb://...
    username: <app_user>
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
  liquibase:
    default-schema: my_schema
    user: <admin_user>
    password: ${DB_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
```

I find I also need to add an an 'ADD USER' sql statement to my liquibase changelog, which means I would also need to find a way to propagate a secondary password into the liquibase xml so that it would update on future deployments. But besides that I'm finding if I do not create this alternate login with admin privileges, I get surprisingly odd errors, such as

'org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [call next value for sequence_generator]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement'

I also see an issue during startup, even when I do create this user as an admin:

2020-10-15 18:12:17.953  WARN 86226 --- [    test-task-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
2020-10-15 18:12:19.530 ERROR 86226 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : Hikari - Exception during pool initialization.

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Wrong user name
> or password [28000-200]

It seems like this would be a common use case, so perhaps I'm missing a simpler solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Liquibase & Spring how to use separate user for schema changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774525/liquibase-spring-how-to-use-separate-user-for-schema-changes)

Comment: As a side-note, why using H2 in dev? Use the same database as in production with the testcontainers profile of JHipster (see https://www.jhipster.tech/running-tests/) In addition the idea of using 2 users could be a feature request for JHipster you could open and/or contribute.

Comment: Re the password, you can add environment variables into the changelogs https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changelog-parameters.html