# JHipster H2 DB Non-admin User

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, h2, liquibase

I am trying to run my spring-boot/liquibase/H2 database with a non-admin user and am having some problems understanding how to do this.

First off, I have seen some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774525/liquibase-spring-how-to-use-separate-user-for-schema-changes) and tried to set up my application.yml this way.

```yaml
datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test
    username: USERLIMITED
    password: user_limited_password
liquibase:
    contexts: dev, faker
    user: THELIQUIBASEUSER
    password: THELIQUIBASEPASSWORD
```

Also put these sql statements in the changelog to run so that the user I want is created and given proper access controls:

```html
<sql>DROP USER IF EXISTS USERLIMITED</sql>
<sql>CREATE USER USERLIMITED PASSWORD 'user_limited_password'</sql>
<sql>GRANT ALL ON APP TO USERLIMITED</sql>
```

When trying to start up the app, I get the following error:

```sh
2020-10-21 14:41:18.532 DEBUG 8704 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.config.LiquibaseConfiguration        : Configuring Liquibase
2020-10-21 14:41:18.617  WARN 8704 --- [    test-task-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be
ready at startup!
2020-10-21 14:41:20.226 ERROR 8704 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : Hikari - Exception during pool initialization.

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Wrong user name or password [28000-200]
```

What is interesting is if I change the `LiquibaseConfiguration` file to use synchronous DB configuration vs. the async by default I do not get an error.

```java
// If you don't want Liquibase to start asynchronously, substitute by this:
SpringLiquibase liquibase = SpringLiquibaseUtil.createSpringLiquibase(liquibaseDataSource.getIfAvailable(), liquibaseProperties, dataSource.getIfUnique(), dataSourceProperties);
// SpringLiquibase liquibase = SpringLiquibaseUtil.createAsyncSpringLiquibase(this.env, executor, liquibaseDataSource.getIfAvailable(), liquibaseProperties, dataSource.getIfUnique(), dataSourceProperties);
```

Then if I go to the H2 console and perform a query to see my users I only have the one admin user (which should be a non-admin).

[image]

Trying to log in as the liquibase user that I set up in the yml

```yaml
    user: THELIQUIBASEUSER
    password: THELIQUIBASEPASSWORD
```

is not there and I get the `Wrong user name or password [28000-200]` error.

This leads me to believe that it is something with how the application starts up and asynchronous task execution priority.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: If you think async liquibase is the cause, have you tried to disable it as explained in LiquibaseConfiguration.java?

Comment: Yes, I am currently running it synchronously and do not get an error on build, but it does not create both accounts. I only have the one admin account 'USERLIMITED' which is an admin and the liquibase account does not exists. I am thinking it is an order of events problem even with synchronous loading but I may be missing something on the setup here.

Comment: You could create your user before in an INIT script specified in jdbc URL, see http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#execute_sql_on_connection As a side note, this would be so much easier by replacing h2 by same database as you in prod and testcontainers